# Deep linking opens app with the Launch Activity rather than the Deep Linking Activity inconsistently

Tags: android, xamarin, deep-linking, urbanairship.com, android-deep-link

I implemented deep linking in my Android app with push notification but when I open the app with the push notification deep linking message rather than the Deep Linking Activity, the app opens the launch activity inconsistently. I tried to change `android:launchMode="singleTop"` but did not work. My Deep Linking Activity and Android Manifest code parts are like below.

**Deep Linking Activity:**

```
    [Activity(Label = "DeepLinkingActivity")]
public class DeepLinkingActivity : Activity
{                                                                    
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        if (SessionContext.DeepLinkingMessageContent == null)
        {
            CheckDeepLinkingContent(Intent);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnNewIntent(Intent intent)
    {
        base.OnNewIntent(intent);

        if (SessionContext.DeepLinkingMessageContent == null)
        {
            CheckDeepLinkingContent(intent);
        }
    }

    void CheckDeepLinkingContent(Intent intent)
    {
        if (intent.Data != null)
        {

            var intentData = Intent.Data;
            var hostData = intentData.Host; 
            var path = intentData.Path; 

            var pathContent = path.Split('/');

            //...
            //processing content of the deep linking message

            SessionContext.DeepLinkingMessageContent = deepLinkingContent;

            StartActivity(typeof(LoginView));
            Finish();
        }
    }
```

**Part of Android Manifest:**

```
        <activity android:name="myapp.android.views.DeepLinkingActivity" android:launchMode="singleTop">
        <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data android:scheme="myappscheme" android:host="apphost"/>
       </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: What are the DeepLinkingActivity class attributes and do you have an OnNewIntent override in that singleTop activity?

Comment: I updated the code

Comment: What are the DeepLinkingActivity class attributes ?

Comment: I updated the code again